# Check for 32bit/64bit environment in TFSBuild.proj

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, 64-bit

I have a 32bit build agent on which our MSBuilds run. We recently added a new 64bit machine to our build agent array, but some things in our TFSBuild.proj file is hard coded for a 32bit machine.

Is it possible to check whether the environment being built on is 32 or 64bit?

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot; &quot;$(BuildDirectoryPath)\FooProduct/foo.vdproj&quot; /Build &quot;Release&quot;"/>
```

When running the build on a 32bit machine, it must point to C:\Program Files\... but on a 64bit machine, it must point to C:\Program Files (x86)\...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)` property in MSBuild 4.0.

More details at [MSBuild Reserved Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx).

> The MSBuild subfolder under the
>   \Program Files\ or \Program Files
>   (x86) folder. This path always points
>   to the 32-bit Program Files folder.
>   For example, on a 32-bit machine, the
>   path is to the Program Files folder.
>   For a 64-bit machine, the path is to
>   the Program Files (x86) folder.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         DefaultTargets="Test"
         ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Target Name="Test">
    <Message Text="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```